# IOS swift app not working when using tap Gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, tap

em new to Swift and IOS while developing my first app i am using tap gesture , just dragging and linking it from storyboard to controler view using following code.

@IBAction func taped(_ sender: Any) {

```
        bgimage.isHidden = false
        butn.isHidden = true
        exit.isHidden = false


}
```

now app after loading just showing white blank screen and on Xcode screenshot pages can be seen while ruuning the app as u can see pic in following link 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMIUt.png) [chk here too][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxPZr.png)any help would be appreciated

Comment: theres not link

Comment: show a screenshot of the console. next to the blue button in the bottom-right of your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wired a button to action `handleTap(_)` but you aren't declaring it. Add it,

```
@IBAction func handleTap(_ sender: Any) {
    bgimage.isHidden = false
    butn.isHidden = true
    exit.isHidden = false
}
```

[Also see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)